# How to adjust the width of a pool \ Lane in visio Shape using c#

Tags: c#, shapes, bpmn, visio2013

Hi i was able to adjust all the shapes width and height of visio shapes programatically, but i was not able to adjust the width of the **Pool \ Lane** shape from visio BPMN Shapes.Why doesnt the width is not getting adjusted.

```
   shape.get_CellsSRC((short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisSectionIndices.
                       visSectionObject, (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisRowIndices.
                       visRowXFormIn, (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisCellIndices.visXFormWidth).ResultIU = 15;
```

whatever i tried it only takes the default size **7.25** but the height can be adjusted using the same code as below

```
shape.get_CellsSRC((short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisSectionIndices.
                       visSectionObject, (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisRowIndices.
                       visRowXFormIn, (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisCellIndices.visXFormHeight).ResultIU = 10;
```

How to adjust the width of the **Pool and Lane ** shape in visio 2013 using c#...??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was working with the "Pool / Lane" stencil.  I switched to the "CFF Container" instead and the C# code (same as in the question) allowed me to resize the width of the pool.